# pmvnorm function's arguments in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I was trying to compute the cumulative distribution function of a bivariate Normal random variable by the function `pmvnorm` from `mvtnorm` package.

I don't understand well all the arguments of this function.

Let's go step by step. `pmvnorm` funtion should replicate in R what in statistics is:

P(X <= x, Y<= y)

In order to do so I fed pmvnorm function in this way:

```
pmvnorm(lower = -inf, upper = c(x, y), mean = 0 corr = cor_mat)
```

Even if it looks like working I don't understand what `lower` and `upper` arguments means. I guess that they should be the lower and upper limits of X and Y Normal random variables. If so, `-Inf` and `x` would refer to `X` variable, saying that it should compute the probability from -Inf to x. And `-Inf` and `y` would refer to Y variable, saying that it should compute the probability from -Inf to y.

Is this interpretation right?

Let's say, now I would like to translate this statistic situation:

P(x_2 < X <= x_1, Y<= y)

into pmvnorm syntax. How should I write it? Following the previous interpretation I would write:

```
pmvnorm(lower = c(x_2, -inf), upper = c(x_1, y), mean = 0 corr = cor_mat)
```

But this time it does not work, since I get numbers greater than 1, which it is impossibile since it should be a probability.

Comment: The function documentation may help:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mvtnorm/versions/0.1-8/topics/pmvnorm

Comment: What values of `cor_mat` and `x_1` and `x_2` are you actually using? What is the probability you get and what do you expect?

Comment: As an example, x_1=1, x_2=0, y=1, and the correlation matrix as a 2x2 identity matrix returns values of <1 for me: `pmvnorm(lower = c(0, -Inf), upper = c(1, 1), mean = 0, corr = diag(2))`.

Comment: A value greater than 1 suggests a broken installation.